# Label with Timer not Stopping

Tags: swift

I am creating a lap stopwatch, and I am having trouble stopping the timer when the "STOP" button is clicked. I am able to get the text to reset to 0, but the timer keeps running and if I hit start again the timer is running as if I never hit stop.

Timer code:

```
    func goTimer()
    {
      if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval : 0.1,
                                     target : self,
                                     selector :#selector(timerAction(_:)),
                                     userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
      }
    }

    func stopTimer()
    {
      if timer != nil {
        timer!.invalidate()
        timer = nil
      }
    }
    
    func updateTimer() {
        let intervalTotal = -Int(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        let hours = intervalTotal / 3600
        let minutes = intervalTotal / 60 % 60
        let seconds = intervalTotal  % 60
        
        if startButton.currentTitle == "STOP" {
            totalTime.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
            lapTime.text = String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
        }
 }

    @objc func timerAction (_ timer : Timer) {
        print("timerAction(_:)")
        self.updateTimer()
    }



    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if startButton.currentTitle == "STOP" {
            startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            startButton.setTitle("START", for : .normal)
            stopTimer()
            lapTime.text = "00:00:00"
        }
        else if startButton.currentTitle == "START" {
            startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
            startButton.setTitle("STOP", for : .normal)
            goTimer()
            lapButton.isEnabled = true
            lapButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you know that timer is not stopping ?

Comment: i think you are not resting startDate

Comment: Where is the target/action method `timerAction`?

Comment: @jawadAli the code must have cut off i will update it with the corrret timerAction code. Also, I  looked up the structure o date and i'm still unfamiliar on how to reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let intervalTotal = -Int(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)`

I don't see you resetting that `startDate` in your `stopTimer()` function.

you have a variable
`var startDate: Date = Date()`
somewhere on top of your code. If its not a variable (if its let) change it to variable. You want to set this value when you start your timer. so

```
func goTimer() {
    // Add this to set the date to when your function starts
    startDate = Date()
    ....
}
```

That's because when you're setting the value in your label here

```
func updateTimer() {
    let intervalTotal = -Int(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow)
    ....
}
```

you're setting the value from startDate until now

Comment: i'm pretty new to swift. I just looked up the date documentation and I'm unclear on how exactly I would reset the date. would i just call startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow again?

Comment: Updated the answer